# Trying to add an Enhanced Ecommerce code to a website using Google Analytics code (not Tag Manager) and need help populating the fields

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

This is for ‘add to basket’ tracking on product pages. How would you go about tracking this (non-tag manager)?

So far what I have is:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-Y");
ga("require", "ec");

ga("ec:addProduct", {
  "id": "OO9238-18",
  "name": "Fives Squared PRIZM™ Shallow Water Polarized",
  "category": "Sunglasses",
  "brand": "Fives Squared",
  "variant": "black",
  "price": "135.00",
  "quantity": 1
});
ga("ec:setAction", "add");
ga("send", "event", "detail view", "click", "addToCart");
```

But the product information needs to be coded as variables rather than strings, i.e. they expect to see 'id': window.someVariable rather than 'id': 'P12345'.  Apparently this can be achieved by using one of the following approaches (or a combination of the two):

--> Make use of an existing global variable that holds product data.

--> Pull in the pertinent information from information within the DOM i.e. from page text or HTML tag attributes.

I don't understand what these are, can anyone help please and tell me what the JavaScript variables are and provide the code?

Thank you! :)